# How to parse a text list with a custom delimiter and key value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have a fairly structured pattern to the data, but I don't know how to efficiently process it.

Right now we have used a for loop to iterate through every row and split on the delimiter and then the value pair but..."There's got to be a better way"

Here's a sample row:

```
|207=NYSE|11002=N|10=232|
```

Some notes about the data

- The pipes are the delimiter, but the document has a custom delimiter
- 207, 11002, and 10 in this example are the variable/column headers
- NYSE, N, and 232 are the values
- Not every variable is guaranteed to be listed in every row
- I believe None/NULL is an empty string `|207=|`

Comment: What you are doing sounds right. Use `readlines()` and `split()`

Comment: Your final statement about None/NULL can't possibly be true given the preceding facts. If it were true then `207=11002=N` is ambiguous.  Does key `207` have no value, a value of `1`, `11`, ...? For that matter how do you decide that `NYSE11002` is value `NYSE` and key `11002`? What does you means "the squares are the custom delimiter"? I suspect your copy/paste dropped some characters.

Comment: @KurtisRader that's really odd. The preview showed the squares, but the actual post does not. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this

```
data = '|207=NYSE|99=|11002=N|10=232|'
```

Then this

```
kv = dict(arg.split('=', 1) for arg in data.split('|') if arg)
```

is perhaps the simplest, most efficient way, to turn it into this dict:

```
{'207': 'NYSE', '99': '', '11002': 'N', '10': '232'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables!

Would need more information but if you already have the data you can sort it into these which can be indexed and decrease the overall process time!

Of course the initial computation of where the entries go will take time but.

Something like

```
def hash(astring, tablesize):
sum = 0
for pos in range(len(astring)):
    sum = sum + ord(astring[pos])

return sum%tablesize
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with hashtables. Sounds like I need to do some reading!

Comment: Fantastic link!

Comment: What in the world does this answer have to do with the question? Furthermore, python already has a perfectly adequate hash table -- it's known as `dict`.